# Are there some other ways to check if smth that is nullable is equals to smth that is nullable too?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert some additional information into my SQL table

```
INSERT -smth- INTO teble_name
SELECT DISTINCT -smth-
FROM table_name first
JOIN table_name second ON 
    first.id1 = second.id2
WHERE first.att = second.att
```

so, it does not work, cause `att` can be `NULL` and `NULL = NULL` does not work well. I also tried `LIKE` instead of `=`, which didn't help me too. Are there some other ways to check if smth that is nullable is equals to smth that is nullable too?

Comment: Not currently. You can vote for the SQL Server connect item to add [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate) but it's been there for almost 10 years now and not much sign that they're planning it any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way I know of than just using `OR` and an `IS NULL` check.

```
WHERE  first.att = second.att 
OR     (first.att IS NULL AND second.att IS NULL);
```

You could try shortening to something like:

```
WHERE   ISNULL(first.att, '') = ISNULL(second.att, '');
```

This is firstly not the same thing, because it leaves the possibility of `first.att` actually being an emtpy string, therefore should not match a null value for `second.att`.

It is also no more efficient, so I would stick to the more verbose version

---

**EDIT**

You could actually shorten it ever so slightly to:

```
WHERE  first.att = second.att OR ISNULL(first.att, second.att) IS NULL;
```

But I stand by my first argument, you only save a few characters, gain nothing in performance, and lose intent.

Comment: The second method can usually be easily fixed by simply replacing the empty string with a value that will never occur in the data.  That said, on reflection I tend to agree that the first example is better.  Intent is clearer.

Comment: thatnks, it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
WHERE coalesce(first.att,-999) = coalesce(second.att,-999)
```

coalesce replaces null with the value you specify.  Just be sure to specify a value that can never occur in the real data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO teble_name(-smth-)
SELECT DISTINCT -smth-
FROM table_name first
JOIN table_name second ON 
    first.id1 = second.id2
WHERE isnull(first.att,0) = isnull(second.att,0)
```

Comment: This is fine as long as zero cannot actually occur in the data as a value of `att`.

Comment: if att column is numeric using "0" otherwise you can use ' ' instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT -smth- INTO teble_name
SELECT DISTINCT -smth-
FROM table_name first
JOIN table_name second ON 
    first.id1 = second.id2
WHERE first.att = second.att OR (first.att IS NULL AND second.att IS NULL )
```

I reasons I would not change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE COALESCE(first.att,'Value for null') = COALESCE(second.att,'Value for null')
```

..are as follows:-

- You end up writing having to write type specific code for the COALESCE function (if your "att" field is a string then the 2nd argument should be a string)
- SQL Server can short-circuit on the first version of the WHERE clause but not on the 2nd.
- You can bet your life that your chosen default value will crop up at a time when it's mission critical that it mustn't and you are on-call